# What is best practice for batch drawing objects with different transformations?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I'm conceptualising a good approach to rendering as many disjointed pieces of geometry with a single draw call in OpenGL, and the wall I'm up against is the best way to do so when each piece has a different translation and maybe rotation, since you don't have the luxury of updating the model view uniform between single object draws.  I've read a few other questions here and elsewhere and it seems the directions people are pointed in are quite varied. It would be nice to list the main methods of doing this and attempt to isolate what is most common or recommended. Here are the ideas I've considered:

[edit: removed mention of Instancing as it doesn't really apply here]

1. Creating matrix transformations in the shader. Here I'd send a translation vector or maybe a rotation angle or quaternion as part of the attributes. The advantage is it would work cross-platform including mobile. But it seems a bit wasteful to send the exact same transformation data for every single vertex in an object, as an attribute. Without instancing, I'd have to repeat these identical vectors or scalars for a single object many many times in a VBO as part of the interleave array, right? The other drawback is I'm relying on the shader to do the math; I don't know if this is wise or not.
2. Similar to 1), but instead of relying on the shader to do the matrix calculations, I instead do these on the client side but still send through the final model view matrix as a stream of 16 floats in the VBO. But as far as I can tell, without instancing, I'd have to repeat this identical stream for every single vertex in the VBO, right? Just seems wasteful. The tradeoff with 2) above is that I am sending more data in the VBO per vertex (16 floats rather than a 3-float vector for translation and maybe a 4 float quaternion), but requiring the shader to do less work.
3. Skip all the above limitations and instead compromise with a separate draw call for each object. This is what is typically "taught" in the books I'm reading, no doubt for simplicity's sake.

Are there other common methods than these?

As an academic question, I'm curious if all the above are feasible and "acceptable" or if one of them is clearly a winner over the others? If I was to exclusively use desktop GL, is instancing the primary way for achieving this?

Comment: Good question, I'd love to see a discussion of the various pros and cons of these various techniques.

Comment: This is far too hardware specific to give any reasonable or accurate recommendations across such a wide variety of hardware platforms. Even just a discussion of when it's appropriate to use instancing is too hardware specific. You're basically talking about a month-long profiling research project.

Comment: @NicolBolas okay.... so suppose we omit a discussion about instancing; are you saying that a discussion about the other techniques has no point? People try all sorts of things with VBOs and shaders, surely there is some general ideas about what to be aware of, or reasons why some of these suggestions aren't good at all, etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas for example it would be useful to hear thoughts about whether sending object-wide constants like a modelview as vertex attributes is better than just using separate draw calls.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: "*omit a discussion*" This is Stack Overflow; *discussion* is not what we do here. We want concrete questions with specific answers, not invitations for discussion. Furthermore, the answers to these questions require (in addition to hardware info) *detailed* information about what exactly you're trying to render. The question is simply unanswerable in any way beyond people spitballing generalities and unvarnished opinions based on arbitrary conditions that any particular user may not be working with. Your question is simply not specific enough to be answerable.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: First, don't make this about *me*. I'm [just enforcing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37682) the [community standards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16599) (which I happen to agree with). Discussiony-type questions and "best practice" questions aren't what we do here. Second, discussions are best done in a forum, not a Q&A format. I only know of one forum dedicated to OpenGL (and *desktop* GL at that). And it appears [you've found it](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181519), so I'm not really sure why you asked.

Comment: @NicolBolas btw your own interpretation of those questions on Meta you linked to is also a bit subjective.. Consider these replies in those questions... *"if you are discussing best practice, those are generally much more acceptable"* and *"Are 'best practices' questions bad? Not inherently; questions on processes tend to come up fairly often, and while yes, they are inherently subjective, there's something to be said for just answering them"*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two considerations:

> Generally speaking, if you have multiple objects, with each object
>   using independent transforms, you use multiple draw calls. That's what
>   they're there for. The old NVIDIA "Batch Batch Batch" presentation
>   cited between 10,000 and 40,000 draw calls per-frame (in D3D. More in
>   GL) for a 1GHz GPU. Nowadays, you're looking at rather more than that.
>   So unless you're dealing with tens of thousands of individual objects,
>   all of them being different (so no instancing), odds are good that
>   you'll be fine.

Another idea:

> Take the modelview matrix calculations out of the shader entirely and just pass the vertices after multiplication. This allows a single draw call for many objects in different orientations and translations. The cost just comes at all the CPU calculations, but I suppose if that bottleneck is not as big as the bottleneck of multiple draw calls, it would be worth it.

(Taken from [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181519-What-is-best-practice-for-batch-drawing-objects-with-different-transformations?p=1250196#post1250196).)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternate idea:

Give each vertex an object ID that is passed in via an attribute. Then in the vertex shader, use this ID to do a lookup in a texture where you store your transformation matrices.

Comment: Ah, texture lookups. You bet, i like it. Thanks.

Comment: I've played with this approach, it's sort of like Sprites. You have to push the texture each time, of course, but it's just a handful, much smaller than the vertices.

In my simplified case, I just used vec4s in one row for xyz-translation plus a y-rotation. A full matrix in the texture may not always be needed.